# Python: How to find scrambled words in a wordlist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to unscramble words and find them in a wordlist. Everything works fine but every time I run the script, it returns different output.

ie. my scrambled words are:

> ctatmo hesena eysrrh nsgesei ncctone phjeso htdgwi lrqaeu gcsoguo
>   rmuhpy

first output:

> sheena,genesis,raquel,sherry,murphy,dwight,gocougs,tomcat,joseph,connect

second output:

> sheena,tomcat,murphy,raquel,sherry,genesis,connect,dwight,joseph,gocougs

I want to print these words in the same order as scrambled ones - ctatmo = tomcat, hesena = shena and etc. and I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Here is my code:

```
from random import shuffle
from os import system

x = 0
wordlist = []
passlist = []
correct_passwords = []
bad = []

def add_words():
    dic = open('wordlist.txt')

    for line in dic.readlines():
        wordlist.append(line.strip())
    dic.close()

    pwd = open('stuff.txt')

    for line in pwd.readlines():
        passlist.append(sorted(line.strip()))
    pwd.close()

def shuffle_words(args):
    args = list(args)
    shuffle(args)
    global shuffled_word
    shuffled_word = ''.join(args)

def check_if_correct():
    if (shuffled_word in wordlist) and (shuffled_word not in correct_passwords):
        correct_passwords.append(shuffled_word)
    else:
        bad.append(shuffled_word)

def copy_to_clip():
    stuff = '{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(correct_passwords[0],correct_passwords[1],correct_passwords[2],correct_passwords[3],correct_passwords[4],correct_passwords[5],
        correct_passwords[6],correct_passwords[7],correct_passwords[8],correct_passwords[9])
    cmd = 'echo '+stuff.strip()+'|clip'
    return system(cmd)

def main():
    add_words()
    while len(correct_passwords) < 10:
        for words in passlist:
            shuffle_words(words)
            check_if_correct()
    print(correct_passwords)
    copy_to_clip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Could someone help me? I'm newbie at python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why on earth are you using echo? You also realise the purpose of shuffle is to give you a random ordering?

Comment: He's using `shuffle` to try different orderings for each string until it matches one in the word list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `random.shuffle()` to try random orderings until you find one that matches, so you find the correct orderings for words in different orders each time you run the script.

That's the answer to the question, but let me just mention that there are better ways to do this than trying random orders until you find a match. You might want to open another question regarding ways to improve the code, perhaps on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).